# Using AppleScript to click the plus (+) button in a preferences window

Tags: applescript

Using AppleScript I would like to automate the creation of a new user accounts on multiple machines. I'm trying to use UI Scripting and cannot seem to be able to do a click command on the "Add Account" (+) button in the iChat Accounts Preference window. I've tried to use the Accessibility Inspector.app to infer the name of the button but I still cannot seem to access it via AppleScript.

According to Accessibility Inspector.app the button has the following attributes:

```
AXRole: AXButton
AXRoleDescription: button
AXHelp: <nil>
AXEnabled: YES
AXFocused (W): NO
AXParent: <AXGroup>
AXWindow: <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXTopLevelUIElement: <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXPosition: x=225.00 y=462.00
AXSize: w=23.00 h=22.00
AXTitle: <empty string>
AXIdentifier: _NS:27
AXDescription: Add Account
```

Here is a sample starter AppleScript that will get you to the Accounts Preference window:

```
tell application "iChat"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iChat"
            tell menu bar 1
                click menu item "Preferences…" of menu "iChat"
            end tell
            click button "Accounts" of tool bar 1 of window 1
            click button "Add Account" of window "Accounts"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Please note that line 9 is what I'm trying to get working. Below you will find a link to a screenshot of the iChat Accounts Preference window with an arrow pointing to the button that I'm trying to access. Also note that I know that I can just use "keystroke tab" to get to the (+) button, but this will not always work as the number of times you must press tab changes depending on the type of accounts that you already created in iChat.

[iChat Account Preferences Window](https://skitch.com/psyrendust/gdxq8/accounts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every Ui object has a title, so in those cases you can just use the item number - note that you need to include the entire hierarchy shown in the Inspector window.

```
tell application "iChat"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iChat"
            tell menu bar 1 to click menu item "Preferences…" of menu "iChat"
            delay 0.5
            tell window 1
                click button "Accounts" of tool bar 1
                delay 0.5
                click button 1 of group 1 of group 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```